# Convert byte array of docx format to byte array of pdf format directly

Tags: java, aspose

Is there is any possible way to Convert byte array of docx/txt or of any format  to byte array of pdf format directly, without creating pdf file.

Comment: This is contradictory. "Converting docx to pdf" *is* "creating a pdf file". You just did not save it to disc ...

Comment: Yes you can write to a **ByteArrayOutputStream** and then take its byte  array. One needs a conversion library.

Answer (score 0):

I believe, you can achieve this by using the following code of [Aspose.Words for Java](http://www.aspose.com/java/word-component.aspx):

```
ByteArrayInputStream inStream = byte array of DOCX/TXT;
// Load Document from inStream
Document doc = new Document(inStream);

/* Perform any document processing tasks here */

// Save the modified document into out stream
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
doc.save(baos, SaveFormat.PDF);

// You can then get the PDF document back into the InputStream as follows
InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());
```

Please also check the [file formats that you can currently convert to PDF](http://www.aspose.com/api/java/words/com.aspose.words/constants/LoadFormat) (byte array or save to disk) using Aspose.Words for Java. I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.